# how to download sintel files?

Tags: modeling, animation

I know that sintel files were distributed under the GPL and also found mention that the files were for public, however, in the download section of [sintel's official site](https://durian.blender.org/news/sintel-lite/), there's only a lite version of sintel's model and textures used. Is there another site to download the files used in the movie or do we have to purchase them? I would like to study the files for animation and modelling purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know you can only access the full files of Sintel, and all other Open Movies on the Blender Cloud, which is $10 per month. So the full files "should" not be open freely for everyone on the web. Also Blender Cloud offers many awesome products and tutorials so the money is worth. [Blender Cloud](https://cloud.blender.org/)